# React native, app crash on release apk after installing jitsi meet

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I installed `reat-native-jitsi-meet` and followed all the steps from documentation. But my app starts crashing on release mode and it's working on debug mode. I can't figure out what's the problem.

I added this lines in my android/app/build.gradle file

```
project.ext.react = [
        enableHermes: true,  // clean and rebuild if changing    entryFile: "index.js",
        entryFile: "index.js",
        bundleAssetName: "app.bundle",
]
....
   packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86/libjsc.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libjsc.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libjsc.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libjsc.so'
    }
....
 implementation(project(':react-native-jitsi-meet'))  {
        //   exclude group: 'com.facebook.react',module:'react-native-locale-detector'
        exclude group: 'com.facebook.react',module:'react-native-vector-icons'
        // Un-comment below if using hermes
        exclude group: 'com.facebook',module:'hermes'
        // Un-comment any packages below that you have added to your project to prevent `duplicate_classes` errors
        exclude group: 'com.facebook.react',module:'react-native-community-async-storage'
        //   exclude group: 'com.facebook.react',module:'@react-native-async-storage/async-storage '
        //   exclude group: 'com.facebook.react',module:'react-native-community_netinfo'
        //exclude group: 'com.facebook.react',module:'react-native-svg'
        //exclude group: 'com.facebook.react',module:'react-native-fetch-blob'
        //exclude group: 'com.facebook.react',module:'react-native-webview'
        //exclude group: 'com.facebook.react',module:'react-native-linear-gradient'
        //exclude group: 'com.facebook.react',module:'react-native-sound'
    }
```

this lines in android/build.gradle

```
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven { // <---- Add this block
            url "https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-maven-repository/raw/master/releases"
        }
```

this line in mainAPplication

```
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
...
    @Override
          protected @Nullable String getBundleAssetName() {
              return "app.bundle";
          }
```

and these lines in mainfest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" //this line
  package="com.superstudent">

 <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
      android:allowBackup="false"
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup" //this line
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

     <activity android:name="com.reactnativejitsimeet.JitsiMeetNavigatorActivity" />
```

I can't figure out what's the problem. Anyone here can help me please?